# Поставить chechbox и активировать кнопку через консоль браузера

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Подскажите пожалуйста как через консоль браузера поставить галочку и тем самым разблокировать кнопку? Желательно конечно так же и нажать данную кнопку.

```js
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  if (nodes[i].type == "checkbox")
    nodes[i].checked = true;
}
```

Данный код только ставит галочку, но кнопку не разблокирует.

```html
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="check" id="agree" onclick="checkAgree(this)" />
Я прочитал и согласен с
<u>
  <a href="../rules/">
    <span style="color:#0000ff;">
      Правилами
    </span>
  </a>
</u>.
<br />
<input disabled="" type="submit" name="circles" value="Заказать" />
```

Галочка не стоит:

```
<input type="submit" name="circles" value="Заказать" disabled="">
```

Галочка стоит:

```
<input type="submit" name="circles" value="Заказать">
```

Comment: `nodes[i].removeAttribute("disabled");`

Comment: Спасибо, кнопка стала активной. Подскажите пожалуйста какой командой можно нажать данную кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).forEach(input => {

  if (input.type == 'checkbox') {
  
    input.checked = true;
    input.click();
  }
  
  
  if (input.type == 'submit') {
  
    input.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
  
});





function checkAgree(e) {

  console.log('Agree:', e);
}
```

```html
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="check" id="agree" onclick="checkAgree(this)" />
Я прочитал и согласен с
<u>
  <a href="../rules/">
    <span style="color:#0000ff;">
      Правилами
    </span>
  </a>
</u>.
<br />
<input disabled="" type="submit" name="circles" value="Заказать" />
```

Исходя из вопроса ничего не понятно.

1. Если нужна кнопка, то вместо `<input type='submit'>` лучше использовать кнопку `<button>`
2. Значениe атрибута не обязательно указывать `disabled=""`, можно просто `disabled`
3. Такие методы как `getElementsById`, `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName` и т.д. устарели. Лучше всего использовать `element.querySelector('#id')`, `element.querySelector('.className')` и `element.querySelector('tag')` или `element.querySelectorAll('input')` для множества.

```js
let checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'));
let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));



checkboxes.forEach(input => input.checked = true);



buttons.forEach(button => {

  button.removeAttribute('disabled');
  button.click();
});



function checkAgree(button) {

  console.log('Agree:', button);
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox'>
<span>Я прочитал и согласен с <a href='../rules/' style='color: #0000ff; text-decoration: none;'>Правилами</a></span><br><br>
<button onclick='checkAgree(this)' disabled>Заказать</button>
```

Comment: Это не мой сайт, мне необходимо через браузер имитировать нажатие кнопки. С помощью этого я смог разблокировать кнопку и поставить галочку: var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
 for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  if (nodes[i].type == "checkbox")
   nodes[i].checked = true;
   nodes[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
 }

Comment: @Даниил, так там два разных input. Нажатие имитируется через `nodes[i].click();`

Comment: @Даниил `input.click()` нужно поставить в соответствующее условие для `submit` или `checkbox`

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!

Comment: @Даниил конечно можно. Вопрос только по какому месту нажимать. По всему документу или конкретному элементу